# como obtener el valor de un botton

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Definí una tabla y cada una de las celdas contiene un botón. Mi problema es al ejecutar el método click() de jquery me devuelve siempre el valor correspondiente al primer botón.

Adjunto el código

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".boton").click(function(){
        alert($(".boton").attr("value"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="15:00">15:00</button></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="15:20">15:20</button></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="15:40">15:40</button></td>
      <!--<td class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="15:45">15:45</button></td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="16:00">16:00</button></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="16:20">16:20</button></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="16:40">16:40</button></td>
      <!--<td class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="16:45">16:45</button></td>-->
    </tr>
         </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="alta">
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Aguardo comentarios.

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Al momento de ejecutar el evento, debes hacer referencia a `this` para capturar el valor del botón al cual se le hizo `click`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".boton").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="15:00">15:00</button></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="15:20">15:20</button></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="15:40">15:40</button></td>
      <!--<td class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="15:45">15:45</button></td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="16:00">16:00</button></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="16:20">16:20</button></td>
      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="16:40">16:40</button></td>
      <!--<td class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" value="16:45">16:45</button></td>-->
    </tr>
         </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="alta">
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa data-attributes

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success boton" data-value="15:00">15:00</button>

$(".boton").click(function(){
        alert($(".boton").data("value"));
    });
```

Quiza te pueda servir